# How to disable a selected option from dynamically loaded options

Tags: jquery

I have a button that whenever is clicked will add another dropdown and I am dynamically creating its options from my database through `ajax`.

Below is **my code**:

`HTML` for button and select:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success w-100 fake_add" style="margin-top: 0;">Add row</button>

<select class="form-control inv_list inv_item_list1"></select>
```

`jQuery` for loading option items and dynamically adding another select dropdown:

```
let option = ''

function load_items() {
    $.ajax({
        url : `${base_url}customized/Upload_sales_data/get_items`,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(items) {
            option = '<option value="" selected hidden>Select Item</option>'

            items.map(function(item){
                option += `<option value="${item.id}">${item.itemname}</option>`
            })

            $('.inv_item_list1').html(option)
        }
    })
}

load_items() /*Function call*/

/* Add new field */
$(document).on('click', '.fake_add', function(){
    count = $('.field_wrapper #inv_item_list').length
    count++

    let newfield = `
    <div class="discount_row row">
        <div class="col-md-3 pl-0 mb-1">
            <select class="form-control inv_list inv_item_list${count}" id="inv_item_list">
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 mb-1 text-left text-red">
            <i class="fa fa-trash fake_delete" style="font-size: 30px;"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    `
    $('.field_wrapper').append(newfield)
    $(`.inv_item_list${count}`).html(option)
})
```

My question is, how can I disable those options that were selected from the previous dropdowns?

Comment: take one array, and push selected option value in that array. so when new dropddown is creating check if array contains that item then make it disable.

Comment: should i pass that array to my function? I'm only calling it once tho when the page loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon changing the selected option, pass the value or text in an array.

Then after creating the new select element check if the value or text of the new select element is in the array by using this code:

```
$(`.new_select`).find("option").filter(function () {
    for (i = 0; i < selected_array.length; i++) {
        if ($(this).html() == selected_array[i])
            $(this).attr("disabled", true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one array so you can track previeous selected dropdwon values.

when you are adding new dropdwon, first add last dropdown value in array.

```
$(document).on('click', '.fake_add', function(){

 myselectedOptions.push($('#dropdownId').children("option:selected").val());

})

let option = '';
var myselectedOptions = [];

function load_items() {
    $.ajax({
        url : `${base_url}customized/Upload_sales_data/get_items`,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function(items) {
            option = '<option value="" selected hidden>Select Item</option>'

            items.map(function(item){
             if(myselectedOptions.indexOf(item.id) > 0)
             {
                option += '<option disabled value="${item.id}">${item.itemname}</option>'
             }
            else
            {
              option += '<option value="${item.id}">${item.itemname}</option>'
            }
         })
            $('.inv_item_list1').html(option)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me. Note that im only calling load_items() once when the page loads since it also reloads the first drop down for every call. The global variable 'option' is what I'm calling for the newly added fields.

Comment: then add array push code into place before your new dropdown is loaded